# Install pipenv and project dependencies using a makefile

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, pip, pipenv

I want to create a make file using which I can automate the virtual environment creation and installation of project dependencies. I've create the following rule:

```
setup-env:
    sudo apt-get install python3 pip
    pip install pipenv
    pipenv shell
    pipenv install
```

I am able to install python, pipenv and create a virtual environment.

But the last line ***pipenv install*** is not getting execute because the control shifts to virtual environment. When I exit from the virtual environment, the ***install*** command gets executed.

Is there a way to install dependencies without creating a separate rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple install before going into the shell
(pipenv can be installed outside the shell)

change the order of your rules:

```
setup-env:
    sudo apt-get install python3 pip
    pip install pipenv
    pipenv install
    pipenv shell
```

Comment: I'd tried doing this. But I get an error when I try to install dependencies without entering the shell.

**To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.**



**Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.**

Comment: @HarshPancholi I dont think its an error, are you sure it doesn't create the venv? i think it is only a message saying that you need to do this `pipenv shell` to enter the shell it self

Comment: Alright. If we try to install packages without entering the venv, where do the packages get installed? Is it the same thing as entering a venv and installing the packages?

Comment: @HarshPancholi its depeneds on your settings, and if you have a `.env` folder in your project, you can read about it its pretty simple, or you can just export `export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1`